# Prove that $P\left(A_{1}+A_{2}+\ldots+A_{n}\right) \leq P\left(A_{1}\right)+P\left(A_{2}\right)+\ldots+P\left(A_{n}\right)$

Tags: probability-theory

**Question:**  For $n$ events $A_{1}, A_{2}, \ldots . ., A_{n}$ in a probability space show that
$$
P\left(A_{1} A_{2} \ldots A_{n}\right) \geq P\left(A_{1}\right)+P\left(A_{2}\right)+\ldots+P\left(A_{n}\right)-(n-1)
$$
Hence deduce $P\left(A_{1}+A_{2}+\ldots+A_{n}\right) \leq P\left(A_{1}\right)+P\left(A_{2}\right)+\ldots+P\left(A_{n}\right)$.

Progress: Proof :
We have by Boole's inequality
$$
P\left(\bar{A}_{1}+\bar{A}_{2}+\cdots+\bar{A}_{n}\right) \leqslant P\left(\bar{A}_{1}\right)+P\left(\bar{A}_{2}\right)++\cdots+P\left(\bar{A}_{n}\right)
$$
or. $\quad P \overline{\left(A_{1} A_{2} \ldots \ldots A_{n}\right)} \leqslant P\left(\bar{A}_{1}\right)+P\left(\bar{A}_{2}\right)+\ldots+P\left(\bar{A}_{n}\right)$
by De Morgan's law.
$\begin{array}{ll}\text { or, } & 1-P\left(A_{1} A_{2} \ldots \ldots A_{n}\right) \leqslant P\left(\bar{A}_{1}\right)+P\left(\bar{A}_{2}\right)+\cdots+P\left(\bar{A}_{n}\right) \\ \text { or, } & P\left(A_{1} A_{2} \ldots \ldots A_{n}\right) \geqslant 1-\sum_{i=1}^{n} P\left(\bar{A}_{i}\right)\end{array}$.

Now $P\left(\bar{A}_{i}\right)=1-P\left(A_{i}\right)\implies 1-\sum_{i=1}^{n} P\left(\bar{A}_{i}\right)=1-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left\{1-P\left(A_{i}\right)\right\}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} P\left(A_{i}\right)-(n-1)$.

From these we can prove the first part.

How can I deduce the last part from first part?

Comment: **Hint** $:$ Apply induction on $n \geq 2.$ The base case $n = 2$ is trivial. Which follows from the fact that $$n (A_1 \cup A_2) = n (A_1) + n(A_2) - n (A_1 \cap A_2).$$Now can you proceed?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $:$ Apply the first part on $P\left (A_1^c A_2^c \cdots A_n^c \right )$ and use De Morgan's law to deduce the second part.

Answer (score 0):

We have
P(A1+A2+A3...An) which is equal to [n(A1+A2+A3...An)]/n(S); where n(.) represents the cardinality of the set and S denotes the universal set

Also P(A1)=n(A1)/n(S)
P(A2)=n(A2)/n(S) and so on.

So, P(A1)+P(A2)+..P(An)=[n(A1)/n(S)]+[n(A2)/n(S)]+..

=> P(A1)+P(A2)+..=[n(A1)+n(A2)..n(An)]/n(S)

Also,

n(A1+A2+A3..An)<=n(A1)+n(A2)..n(An)

Hence P(A1+A2+A3...An)<=P(A1)+P(A2)+..P(An)

Comment: @ SS Thank you for your answer. Your solution is correct but it is not driven from first part. I need the proof of last part from first part.